# Issue with Room persistence after compilation

Tags: android, android-room

I have 2 data classes which are annotated with `@Entity` and proper configuration for Room to know what to compile.

For one of the classes, the build time fails and Android Studio yells at me saying that Room cannot find setters for field. With a little research , I changed my `val`s into `var`s and provided an empty constructor. Question is: Why the same problem doesn't happen with my other class which holds `val`s.

```
@Entity(tableName = "names_of_creator")
data class Name(
    @SerializedName("name")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "arabic_name")
    var arabicName: String,

    @SerializedName("transliteration")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "transliteration")
    var transliteration: String,

    @SerializedName("number")
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    var number: Int,

    @SerializedName("en")
    @Ignore
    var englishNameMeaning: EnglishNameMeaning?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name_meaning")
    var meaning: String
){
    constructor(): this("", "", 0, null, "")
}

@Entity(
    tableName = "ayas",
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = Surah::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("surah_number"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("surahs_number"),
        onDelete = CASCADE
    )]
)

data class Aya(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "aya_id")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,

    @SerializedName("audio")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "audio_url")
    val audioUrl: String,

    @SerializedName("text")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "ayat_text")
    val ayatText: String,

    @SerializedName("numberInSurah")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "ayat_number")
    val ayatNumber: Int,

    @SerializedName("juz")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "juz_number")
    val juz: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "surahs_number", index = true)
    val surahNumber: Int
)
```

Comment: Could you post your actual error log? Why do you use `@Ignore` at `englishNameMeaning`?

Comment: Because I don't need it. Ok I'm updating with the error.

Comment: `Error:Cannot find setter for field id = 0` same error is with `transliteration` and `arabicName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Room* will use a constructor to create the object. It'll use one it has all parameters available for. Since you `@Ignore` the `englishNameMeaning`, *Room* doesn't know which value to use. So just define a default value for this parameter.

```
@Entity(tableName = "names_of_creator")
data class Name(
    @SerializedName("name")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "arabic_name")
    val arabicName: String,

    @SerializedName("transliteration")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "transliteration")
    val transliteration: String,

    @SerializedName("number")
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val number: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name_meaning")
    val meaning: String

    @SerializedName("en")
    @Ignore
    val englishNameMeaning: EnglishNameMeaning? = null,
)
```

When *Room* doesn't want to support the *Kotlin* default argument, you might need to annotate the constructor with `@JvmOverloads`.

```
@Entity(tableName = "names_of_creator")
data class Name @JvmOverloads constructor(
    ...
)
```

Comment: which one to annotate with `@JvmOverloads` in data classes?

Comment: You should annotate the primary constructor. You should not need a secondary constructor at all.